# Using an StringIO object for holding uu.encode/uu.decode data

Tags: python, encoding

I would like to do the following:

```
import StringIO, uu
my_data = StringIO.StringIO() # this is a file-like object
uu.encode(in_file, my_data)
# do stuff with my data (send over network)
uu.decode(my_data, out_file) # here I finally write to disk
```

The above code works. However, if I implement the previous step as a property in an object:

```
@property
def content(self):
 out = StringIO.StringIO()
 uu.decode(self._content, out)
 return out.getvalue()
@content.setter
def content(self, value):
 self._content = StringIO.StringIO()
 with open('value', 'rb') as stream:
  uu.encode(stream, self._content)
```

but when I do it like that, `self._content` is empty (`None`, to be precise). Any ideas?

Comment: The `open('value', 'rb')` tries to open a file on disk named `"value"` in read-only binary mode, right? I am not sure, looking at your code, where that file comes from.

Comment: @Brandon Sorry, you are right, it should read `value` (no quotes) and it is a parameter passed to the method with the file name (a string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self._content` is left with the "current point" at its **end** after the `content.setter` method has written to it.  You probably want to add `self._content.seek(0)` at the end of that method so you can next *read* that pseudo-file from the **beginning** (reading while starting from the end will return "nothing more", quite correctly since it does start at the end, and that's probably what's leaving you with the impression that it's "empty";-).

Comment: Thank you, Alex. Please let me experiment with this.